# spring boot with JAX-RS resources

Tags: jax-rs, spring-boot

How do I configure JAX-RS resources with spring boot to be available with the embedded tomcat container?

Below is the JAX-RS resource I have (Groovy):

```
@Component
@Path('files')
@CompileStatic
class MyResource  {
    @Autowired
    FileRepository repository

    @GET
    @Path('{id}')
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response getFileDetails(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        println "getFileDetails called with $id"
        return Response.ok().build()
    }
```

}

When I try http GET with localhost:8080/files/123 I get 404 error. What am I missing?
I do not see errors during tomcat startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to specify jersey SpringServlet in SpringApplication.run. That fixed it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(
                [SpringServlet.class,
                "classpath:/META-INF/bootstrap.xml"] as Object [], args)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fredrik `com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:1.16`. I was still on Jersey 1.x